# Can't get values from datalist in js

Tags: javascript, forms, input, console, new-operator

I am trying to get values out of a datalist form but it seems that there's a bug in my script for my 'input#date' and my 'input#idPosition'

Console says :

{person: 'Etudiant', idPosition: input#idPosition, fact: 'Harcèlement', loc: "Dans l'établissement", date: input#date, …}
anon: "Oui"
date: input#date
fact: "Harcèlement"
idPosition: input#idPosition
loc: "Dans l'établissement"
msg: null
person: "Etudiant"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Could you help ?

---

there is no error report, only i can't get the value out of this input cause it shows 'date: input#date' instead of the value inside it ..

Comment: Your idPosition: input#idPosition and date: input#date and idPosition: input#idPosition
The values of these data are not wrapped in quotes, did you set the wrong values?

Answer (score 0):

nope, those are the right ones
const stalkingForm = document.querySelector('#stalkingForm');

stalkingForm.addEventListener('submit', addForm);

```
function addForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(stalkingForm);
    const person = formData.get('person');
    const position = formData.get('idPosition');
    const fact = formData.get('fact');
    const loc = formData.get('loc');
    const name = formData.get('date');
    const msg = formData.get('msg');
    const anon = formData.get('anon');
    console.log('form', {person, idPosition, fact, loc, date, msg, anon});
    e.return 
}
```

Comment: input#date is an element, right? Can you capture the full error report? And what do you want the correct result to look like?